# Ubuntu Kinetic 22.10, audio output keeps switching from bluetooth to Unknown device

Tags: sound, firefox, bluetooth, pavucontrol, pipewire

I use Bluetooth audio devices all the time. This was working great on Jammy 22.04 with Pipewire. Once I upgraded to Kinetic, operation got very bumpy. Often (but not always) when I pause a video playing in youtube, the audio output destination will switch from my bluetooth device to "Unknown device." This is relatively easy to fix using pavucontrol to set the output destination again or by disconnecting and reconnecting the bluetooth device. I'm using firefox 107.0b2. Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KSgxFZEZ_X0).

I would file a bug in launchpad, but it's not clear which package is at fault.

Is the problem that I need to select the default output from the [corner output selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqhmw.png)?

Comment: I can confirm this problem do not affects only bluetooth devices but USB devices aswell.